# Windows installation broke down after a reset

Tags: windows

I have recently done a factory reset on my laptop because my Windows installation kept having insane lag spikes and sometimes took forever to start. After the reset all the issues were gone but completely new came to light - half of the system barely works. Whenever I try to install a game, Im just met with an error code and after this happening multiple times, I inspected the programs with DependencyWalker, which reported that half of the required DLLs which were in place simply would report as missing and the other half was reported to be of incompatible architecture - x86, I have no idea why I have x86 DLLs in my system as I have a 64bit x64 Ryzen 7 CPU, so basically any 64bit program dependent on system libraries wont work, as for some reason Windows gods decided to provide me with x86 DLLs. Does anyone know what to do?

Edit - Additional information:

The notebook in question: ASUS TUF Gaming FX505DV-HN227T

Windows version: Windows 10 Home 21H2 (19044.2006)

The most common error code I encounter when launching 64bit programs: 0xc000007b

Also, doing a clean install off a clean new copy of Windows doesnt sound like too much of a good option, as this laptop is heavily dependent on all the drivers that are shipped from the factory, some I couldnt even find online and the ones Windows likes to install as a replacement do more harm than good.

Comment: Please provide more detail, such as laptop, cpu, windows versions, sample error messages, relevant portions of the event log

Comment: It sounds like you may have a hardware and/or driver issue. Use the Manufacturer's Apps, update all drivers, and check all hardware.

Comment: "I'm just met with an error code" - You will have to provide more information if you want assistance with this issue.

Comment: If you reset to as-new, there are **many** Windows, driver and other updates needed to bring the PC up to date. It might have been better to **download the latest** Windows ISO and have updated from that... and it can still be done. rather than perform all updates.

Comment: I have added more important information which might help out, anyone who has the nerves, please take a look